# Room Database returns updated value only after app restart

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i am inserting and deleting a row in room database using following methods of ViewModel class

```
fun insert(rules: TableRules) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insert(rules)
}

fun delete(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.delete(id)
}
```

and retriving the data using this this method of DAO class

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM rules_table")
fun getAlphabetizedRules(): List<TableRules>
```

but i am not getting update data.
i.e when i add one row and then retrive, i will not get newly added row.
i close my app, remove from recent app list, start app again then retrive, then i will get that row.

same thing happens in case of delete also.

what i am missing i above.

Comment: I would guess that you launch `getAlphabetizedRules` right after `insert` and since you're using a launch coroutine, the insertion may be not yet finished when you try to retrieve the data. Either make sure that your insertion is finished or use a flow with Room to get your data as soon as it changes.

Comment: @bcordier i think it is not case of concorancy, as I waited 5 minuts after insertion operation and then retrived, still issue. but when i removed app from recent apps list and start again it worked as expected

Comment: use ``Flow<List<TableRules>>`` as soon as you make the changes in your db flow will throw the newly added value.

Comment: did you get the solution to this issue? I'm facing a similar issue like yours... my SELECT query always return the default value for boolean column. The data is updated when I look at it through database inspector, but for some reason, when I queried it, it will always return false (the default value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching a coroutine queues up work that will complete in the future. If you launch a coroutine and then immediately check the state of the table without waiting for the coroutine to finish, you have a race condition and will likely get the earlier state returned.

You need to call `getAlphabetizedRules()` from inside the same coroutine that you launch to call `insert()` or `delete()` so it is happening after the database change.

Or alternatively, you can create a new coroutine or suspend function that `join`s the returned Job from your existing `insert()` and `delete()` functions. For example:

```
suspend fun deleteAndGetUpdatedList(id: Int): List<TableRules> {
    delete(id).join()
    return repository.getAlphabetizedRules()
}
```

By the way, in your DAO, `getAlphabetizedRules()` should be marked as a `suspend` function to make it easier to use properly (not having to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`  every time you call it.

Comment: I think it is not case of concorancy, as I waited 5 minuts after insertion operation and then retrived, still issue. but when i removed app from recent apps list and start again it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Mark the DAO method with @RawQuery annotation instead of normal @Query.